# Deutsche und italienische Namen für Streichinstrumente

Tags: etymology, music

Zur Grundausstattung eines klassischen Sinfonieorchesters gehören einige Streichinstrumente: Geigen, Bratschen, Celli und Kontrabässe.

Für alle vier gibt es eine italienische Beziechnung:

- *Viola* (Bratsche) als »Urform«;
- *Violine* (Geige), die »kleine Bratsche« oder das »Bratschchen«;
- *Violoncello* (Cello), eigentlich eine »kleine Violone«, wobei die Violone heutzutage selten geworden ist, die Reihe aber sinnvoll zum Bass hin ergänzen würde; und
- *Contrabasso*, eingedeutscht Kontrabass, denn mit ihm kann die *Kontra-Oktave* erreicht werden.

Dass diese italienischen Varianten existieren, und umso bekannter sind, je mehr man musikalisch bewandert ist, verwundert nicht, denn die Instrumentenfamilie stammt, soweit mir bekannt ist, aus Italien.

Geige und Bratsche haben außerdem deutsche Namen. Diese beiden besitzen, soweit ich weiß, keine Kognate im Englischen oder im Skandinavischen, scheinen also Innovationen des Deutschen zu sein. Die anderen beiden haben nur ihre ursprünglichen italienischen Namen. (Den scheinbar deutschen Namen *Kontrabass* würde ich als direkte Übertragung des italienischen abtun, denn die Originalform ist noch klar erkennbar.)

Wie werden die deutschen Namen von Geige und Bratsche etymologisch erklärt, und warum haben Cello und Kontrabass keine deutschen (oder: nichtitalienischen) Namen?

Comment: Bratsche scheint mir nach Wikipedia-Studium von "de-Braccio"zu kommen, also einem Überbegriff für eine Gruppe Instrumente. Dass es den Begriff so nur im Deutschen gibt, erklärte sich dann daher, dass man nur als Deutscher das so verformen kann. Nachtrag: Geige scheint (zumindest nach einer Theorie) ein älteres (ggf. aus dem franz. stammendes) Wort für ein ähnliches Instrument zu sein http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Meyers/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=Meyers&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=IG01738

Comment: + Violine/Geige: engl. _fiddle_ = dt. _Fiedel_

Comment: @Crissov Dt. *Fidel* ≠ engl. *fiddle*

Comment: Das Gleichheitszeichen war im morphologischen Sinne gemeint, nicht im semantischen musiktheoretischen/-historischen. (Für mich klingen alle Streichinstrumente kleiner als eine Gitarre ohnehin fast immer nach leidenden Katzen.)

Comment: @Crissov Eine Gitarre als Streichinstrument ist eine skurrile Vorstellung, ich würde eher von einer Viola da Gamba ausgehen. Da diese kleinen Geigen an sich keinen vollen Klang haben benutzt man im Orchester ja sowieso immer so viele Violinen wie gerade zu bekommen und bezahlbar sind.

Comment: @harper Ach deswegen ist da vorne immer so voll …

Answer (score 5):

Zumindest den zweiten Fragenteil kann ich beantworten.

Es gibt deutsche Namen, wenn auch etwas ungebräuchliche:

- die *Kniegeige* für das Violoncello (zugegebenermaßen auch für die Viola da gamba verwendet)
- die *Bassgeige* für den Kontrabass

Comment: Das könnte man um _Armgeige_ für Bratsche als Übersetzung des italienischen _viola da braccio_ ergänzen, aber auch die „normale“ Geige wird meist auf dem Arm bzw. der Schulter liegend gespielt. Damit würde das Deutsche von der [Geige](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Geige)/Violine als Prototyp ausgehen, das Italienische hingegen von der Bratsche/Viola.

Answer (score 1):

Ich zitiere http://geigenunterricht-nuernberg.net/unterschied-zwischen-geige-und-violine/:

> Die Herkunft des Worts Geige ist nicht eindeutig geklärt. Bereits im
>   12 Jahrhundert findet man die Bezeichnung gīga, später gîge, von der
>   das Wort Geige stammen könnte. Das Wort Gigue als Bezeichnung für ein
>   Streichinstrument wird bereits im 13. Jahrhundert erwähnt.
>
> Die Bezeichnung Violine ist später entstanden und stammt vom
>   französischen vyollon (erste Erwähnung 1523, später violon) oder vom
>   italienischen violino (erste Erwähnung 1535). Die Violine war im 16.
>   Jahrhundert ein volkstümliches Instrument, auf dem man Tanzmusik spielte.

Daraus schließe ich, dass zwar die Ausführung zur Benennung der Instrumente aus dem Italienischen (was ja zeitweise eine "in"-Sprache war), dennoch ist "Geige" anscheinend sogar der ältere Begriff.

Man kann überlegen, ob die "Gigue" als form der Tanzes nicht auch aus diesem Dunstkreis entstanden ist.